# Select and Insert for each symbol in VIM or Emacs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, vim, emacs

Im trying to do this im VIM but im open for emacs too.

Lets say I got a block of code like this.

```
test.butter0.(A, b)
test.butter1.(A, b)
test.butter2.(A, b)
test.butter3.(A, b)
test.butter4.(A, b)
test.butter5.(A, b)
```

And now I press Control V and I select all of the "." Symbols. Now I want to press Colon ":" and insert colon for each individual "." symbol.

So select and then press a Key and insert that key in each place of the selected symbol or letter. Also would be awesome if I can also copy one symbol or string from my file and then select all period or @ sings or all numbers or any vertical column of symbols and paste it but replace it for each symbol selected.

like this:

```
test:butter0.(A, b)
test:butter1.(A, b)
test:butter2.(A, b)
test:butter3.(A, b)
test:butter4.(A, b)
test:butter5.(A, b)
```

or

```
test.butter@.(A, b)
test.butter@.(A, b)
test.butter@.(A, b)
test.butter@.(A, b)
test.butter@.(A, b)
test.butter@.(A, b)
```

Is that possible? and if yes how? If it's not possible, how hard would it be to write a Select+insert for each symbol extension?

Comment: Someone just posted this: %s/\./:/ and it worked. Is it possible to Shortcut it to a key combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just press "r:" (no quotes).
It will replace the whole block with the colon character.

Answer (score 1):

- Select the text block visually as you describe
- press ':'
- `s/\./:/g`

Does that do what you want?

Comment: This will only replace the first "." to ":".

Comment: `:substitute` works with linewise ranges, not block selections.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:1,5s/[0-5]\.(/\@:(/g
```

where 1, 5 => start, end line numbers

Or else select text and then use

```
:'<,'>s/[0-5]\.(/\@:(/g
```

Comment: %s/\./:/ works fine man. Is it possible to bind that to let's say: CTR + double V when pasting? so that I can select the entire column of periods with Command+V, then pressing control and twice V to paste it in for each selected character.